# Unable to generate second page of pdf using wkhtmltopdf Php

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Hi,

I have generated the HTML from PDF using conversion tool pdftohtmlEx, Then I am trying to convert this HTML to Pdf by using wkhtmltopdf

Problem i am facing is when HTML has more than one page, it is not generating same number of Pdf pages as like HTML i have.

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmKyE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally Resolved the issue, I have replaced following style generated by pdf2htmlEx

## page-container{bottom:0;right:0;overflow:auto} with

.pf{margin:0;box-shadow:none;page-break-after:always;page-break-inside:avoid}